# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property style of #<HTMLElement> which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The following code fails in Chrome, Safari, works fine in Firefox

```js
"use strict";
document.body.style = "background-color: green;";
```

```html
<p>background should be green</p>
```

Remove the "using strict" and it works.

Is that a bug in Chrome and Safari or a bug in Firefox? [MDN says setting the `style` is valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Comment: Read more carefully.  `styles can not be set by assigning a string to the (read only) style property`

Comment: The code works on Chromium 50 (maybe before).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Problem**

Not all browsers support assigning assigning a string which contains a textual representation of a CSS declaration block to the `style` property.

```js
element.style = styleString; // Might not work
```

**Workaround**

As a workaround, you can set it as a content attribute, or to the [`cssText`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSStyleDeclaration-cssText) property:

```js
element.setAttribute('style', styleString);
```

```js
element.style.cssText = styleString;
```

**Standard behavior**

On older browsers compliant with DOM L2 Style and ES5, the assignment should

- Throw in strict mode
- Be ignored in non-strict mode.

On newer browsers compliant with CSSOM and ES5, the assignment should

- Always work

**Full details**

According to the [DOM Level 2 Style](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ElementCSSInlineStyle) spec, the `style` property is defined in the `ElementCSSInlineStyle` interface as follows:

```
interface ElementCSSInlineStyle {
  readonly attribute CSSStyleDeclaration  style;
};
```

Therefore, the `style` property should be implemented as an [accessor property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10.1) with a getter but without a setter.

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'style'); /* {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  get: function(){...},
  set: undefined
} */
```

According to [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), when you attempt to assign some value to a property like that, an error must be thrown in strict mode:

> When an assignment occurs within [strict mode code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1), [...] the
>   *LeftHandSide* also may not be a reference [...] to an accessor property with the attribute value {[[Set]]:**undefined**} [...]. In
>   these cases a **TypeError** exception is thrown.

However, DOM L2 Style is superseded by the newer CSS Object Model (CSSOM).

According to the that spec, the [`style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-elementcssinlinestyle-style) IDL attribute of the interface [`ElementCSSInlineStyle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#elementcssinlinestyle), implemented by `HTMLElement`, is defined as a [`[PutForwards]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#PutForwards) extended attribute:

```
[NoInterfaceObject]
interface ElementCSSInlineStyle {
  [SameObject, PutForwards=cssText] readonly attribute CSSStyleDeclaration style;
};
```

That means that setting the `style` property must behave like setting the [`cssText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-csstext) one of the `CSSStyleDeclaration`. Therefore, those must be equivalent:

```js
element.style = styleString;
element.style.cssText = styleString;
```

And that's why it works on newer browsers.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Not looking for a workaround

Comment: @gman OK, I have included the explanation. If you are only interested in knowing which implementation is right and not in workarounds, I recommend tagging your question with [\[language-lawyer\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/info).