# Setting Width to Appended Child Image - VANILLA javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built an image slider with jQuery and thought it would be a good exercise to do the same in vanilla javascript (Which is an awesome framework btw ;) ).  It's good to know that though I can build things with jQuery, I have very little understanding of what's actually going on under the hood.

Anyways, here is my problem.  I am trying to set the width of an image that I had appended to a list element.  For some reason, the code I have written is not affecting the width property of the image.  I updated the css as a sanity check and it worked fine, so it must be an issue with the js.

Here is the code:

```
console.log('Yeh, bitch!  Programming!');

function slider() {
var settings = {
    width: "700px"
}; // end settings object

var sliderImages = document.getElementById('slider-images').querySelectorAll('img'),
    prevImg = document.getElementById('prev-img'),
    currentImg = document.getElementById('current-img'),
    nextImg = document.getElementById('next-img'),
    wrapperInner = document.getElementById('img-wrapper-inner'),
    imgList = [],
    imgAttr;

for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
};
function grabImages() {
    var DOM_img;
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        imgSrc = sliderImages[i].getAttribute('src');

        DOM_img = document.createElement('img');
        DOM_img.src = imgSrc;
        imgList.push(DOM_img);
        console.log(imgList[i]);
    }; // end for

    prevImg.appendChild(imgList[imgList.length -1]);
    currentImg.appendChild(imgList[0]);
    nextImg.appendChild(imgList[1]);

}; // end grabImages
grabImages();

var visibleImages = wrapperInner.querySelectorAll('ul li img');
visibleImages.style = 'width: ' + settings.width;

};// end slider
slider();
```

Let me know if you need the css and html.  I'm just trying not to make the post too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` collection, which has no `style` property.

If you want to change the style of every element in that collection, you have to iterate it.

For example, with `[].forEach`:

```
[].forEach.call(visibleImages, function(element) {
  element.style.width = settings.width;
});
```

Note assigning something to the `style` property is a bad practice. On some browsers `style` is implemented as an accessor property with a getter but no setter, so assigning to it will be ignored in non-strict mode or throw in strict-mode. On other browsers, it will replace all the inline styles. Instead, better assign to `style.width`. Or, if you really want to get rid of previous inline styles, to `style.cssText`.

Comment: Thanks.  The last comment about `style.width` and browser compatibility was why I voted yours best answer.

Comment: @user5429729 If you are interested in the assigning to `style` problem you can read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32468442/1529630) where I explained it with detail.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
var visibleImages = wrapperInner.querySelectorAll('ul li img');
visibleImages.style = 'width: ' + settings.width;
```

You are trying to set the style property of a `NodeList` but since it is a list, you can't set a property!

Change it to:

```
var visibleImages = wrapperInner.querySelectorAll('ul li img');
for (var i = 0; i < visibleImages.length; i++)
    visibleImages[i].style = 'width: ' + settings.width;
```

In order to iterate through `visableImages` and set all their styles.